# how to prevent HAML from encoding my helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

So I have this on my helper:

```
    content_tag(:li, "All", { :onclick => %(hideAll(); document.getElementById("vl-body").children[0].style.display = "block") } ) +
```

and HAML produced this:

```
<li onclick="hideAll(); document.getElementById(&quot;vl-body&quot;).children[0].style.display = &quot;block&quot;">All</li>
```

Can't have those encoded quotes.  I wanted to use the % notation instead of the double quote so appreciate help with using the % that HAML won't encode it like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the output you received wrong? What output did you expect instead? What is that "double quote" you are referring to?

Comment: the output i expect is for haml not to encode the quotation marks - as you an see on my example, haml encoded it to "&quot;" how will my inline js code execute now.

Comment: a) You should not have JS in your HTML anyhow, b) Your JS will execute just fine, as `&quot;` will be turned into `"` by the browser parsing the HTML before passing it to the script engine. What Haml is doing here is _correct_. If you had `<li onclick="..."..."...">` I hope you can see that this would be invalid HTML.

Comment: &quot; convert to " by the browser engine? seriously? In any case I get a JS error in my browser. So you mean when you write this out embed in your html it will work? document.getElementById(&quot;someid&quote).innerHTML = "test"

Comment: Yes, seriously. Here is proof: http://jsfiddle.net/BJQWY/ If you are having troubles, this is not it. Post an actual test case of your output as a separate question for more help.

Answer (score 2):

```
#your view

%li#some_id
  All

#application.js without jquery
document.getElementById('some_id').click(function(){
  hideAll(); 
  document.getElementById("vl-body").children[0].style.display = "block";
});
```

Alternative less opinionated answer:

```
content_tag(:li, "All", { :onclick => %(hideAll(); document.getElementById("vl-body").children[0].style.display = "block") } ).html_safe
```

I noticed the trailing plus in your content_tag code, is this important?

Comment: Not at all an answer to the question, but +1 for giving the right answer to how JS should be attached to HTML. (Though you have assumed jQuery, which the OP didn't state and appears not to be using.)

Comment: It's an opinionated answer. :)

Comment: I think it would be even better (usable by the OP without jQuery) if you altered the event binding to `document.getElementById('some_id').onclick = function(){ ... };`

Comment: You're right and done. I see no reason not to use jquery though as everyone's got it in their browser cache.

Comment: i need it to be inline and no jQuery please, I am making a plugin so it would be nice to make sure this will work on any one's platform. so yes i think im still stuck figuring out why my " is being encoded into &quot;